Is it possible to sleep in a JSF application run under WL 12.2?
Technical info: JSF application (2.0) that is deployed as an EAR on a WL 12.2 machine.
Problem: The users of our web application regularly upload DOCX files. But this file type is not allowed for reasons beyond our control. So we use an external REST service to convert those files to PDF. The PDF service is designed for asynchronous calls:

First you call the convert operation with your file, and it returns a task ID
Then you call the getTask operation with the task ID

It's possible that the task is not done yet, so you have to call again later
When the task is done (document converted) you get a document ID


Lastly you call the getDocument operation with the document ID

The user is waiting for a result in the frontend after uploading, so we actually need a synchronous conversion. We keep calling the getTask operation inside a while-loop until we get a document ID. But we received mails from the PDF service complaining that we are polling them too often (10 times / sec) and that we should look for a solution to reduce this.
I added this line of code inside the while-loop to have a 5 second interval between each poll:
Thread.sleep(5000);
But apparently they still keep getting 10 polls per second. I have no idea why the sleep is getting skipped. Is it because of limitations due to JSF or the WebLogic machine?

The Thread.sleep call is perfectly acceptable.  However, if you have a large user base, it is possible for many users to upload Word files simultaneously, in which case you would have many threads all polling the PDF service at the same time.

@VGR I am testing it myself on integration environment so I'm sure it's all from me. But now it seems to work after I have added the synchronized keyword to the method that calls Thread.sleep. Do you think it's an acceptable solution?

That will also depend on the size of your user base.  If you have a lot of users, you don’t want to force your code to run for only one user at a time.  During periods of busy activity, a user might find himself/herself waiting as long as a few minutes for the service to complete.  Most usability studies show that users will give up and leave the page, rather than wait that long for a web application to finish its task.  Perhaps it is worth considering the use of Apache POI and iText, instead of relying on a limited external service.

@VGR The webapp is not public, it's private for a client. They are a team of about 15 people and the convert feature isn't used that often. Would triggering the sleep freeze the server for every user? Or would it specifically freeze for people that are using the convert simultaneously? In any case the convert lasts about 5 seconds so I don't think it's a big deal

It would freeze just for the synchronized part, which I assume is the polling loop.  That’s literally what synchronization is:  a section of code that can only execute for one thread at a time.  But if you only have about 15 users, your approach is probably fine.  I doubt anyone will ever notice a problem.
